cacti setup not working correctly
I tried to install cacti for my two Debian VPS server one has the cacti and other been monitored but when I add the IP address for the server that should be monitored it is giving error message please look at the picture I am not sure even I installed the agent correctly in the second server
picture for the error
I installed cacti in my first VPS and installed many things I even start not to know what should I install in the remote server that should be monitored can you please tell me what should I install in my Linux VPS Debian type to connect to cacti without the error message showing.
